# How would you setup a block listener in rust using web3?

Tags: web3js, accounts, balances, rust

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a function that listens to new blocks and checks for a balance update for an account. I believe you need to use the filter builder but not sure how to keep an open connection and listen for new blocks.

I'm essentially trying to create a small mvp wallet, and unsure how to get new balance updates without the user specifically requesting for a balance update.

Im using web3 for rust.